# File location inside for loop vs. while loop in python

Tags: python

Why does tell() return different answers depending on whether it is called from inside a 'for' loop vs. a 'while' loop? For example, take the following code:

```
tempfile = open(...,'r')
print('for loop:')
for line in tempfile:
    lineStart=tempfile.tell()
    print('line:'+str(lineStart))
tempfile.seek(0)
print('while loop:')
line=tempfile.readline()
while line != '':
    lineStart=tempfile.tell()
    print('line:'+str(lineStart))
    line=tempfile.readline()
```

The output of this is:

```
for loop
line:1014
line:1014
...
line:1014
line:1014
while loop
line:19
line:38
line:64
...
line:1001
line:1011
line:1014
```

Comment: tempfile.seek(0) . did you do the same for ..before ..for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `for line in file` uses a read-ahead buffer, which explains why `.tell()` returns higher numbers in your example.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) (emphasis mine):

> In order to make a `for` loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), **the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer.**

Comment: So I'm assuming this means there is no way for me to use tell() and seek() within the for loop to reposition within the file (back up one line for example)? And therefore I need to go convert all of my for loops to while loops?

Comment: @sagevahi: Yes, I think your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Well that's really unfortunate, but I guess at least I can stop pulling my hair out :) Thanks!!!